# Equal widths in navbar bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, navbar

Need some help styling a navbar with bootstrap 4 and flex box. The design I would like is essentially as below, but I would like the logo in the centre and therefore the space for the links either side to be equal.

```
         --------------------------------------------------------------
|         |    Link  |   Link  |   Logo   |  LongerLink  |  LongerLink |        |
         --------------------------------------------------------------
```

The issue I have at the moment is that the LongerLink items are taking up more space than the shorter Links and so the logo is offset to the left. How do I fix this? Code below.

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: #389FCE;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
}

.navbar-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Nexa-Bold', sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  line-height: 80px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
      <i class="fas fa-bars" style="color:white; font-size:28px;"></i>
    </span>
  </button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav nav-fill w-100">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="shortLink" href="#">HOME</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="shortLink" href="#">ABOUT</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">
          <img src="images/Logo_navbar.png">
        </a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="longLink" href="#">PRODUCTS</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" id="longLink" href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Sorry, centered full width. Will update the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to set widths based on the number of items to do that. There is no flexbox property that will manage it for you.

```
.nav-fill .nav-item {
    flex: 1 0 20%; /* 5 items of 20% each */
    text-align: center;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

[**Codepen Example**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/eYYbPwO)

Comment: Thanks Paulie, this seems to have done the trick. By extension, if I wanted to limit the extent to which the navbar expands (say only 70% of the view width), is there a straightforward way to do this? I'm struggling to find the correct class(es) which would implement this. First figure in original post updated to show what I'm after.

Comment: If you want to limit the width of the navbar just use `max-width:70%`..and center it however you wish.

Answer (score -1):

You can make the nav-item's **flex-basis: 100%** (instead of auto). Also allow them to **shrink** (setting a min-width is also necessary as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size))...

```
.nav-item {
    flex: 0 1 100%;
    min-width: 0.1px;
}
```

Then, you'll need to consider how you want to handle the hiding of overflowing text when the longer links are wider than the other links. I'd use `text-overflow: ellipsis;` like this...

```
.nav-link {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Demo: https://codeply.com/p/N8MvGaunOR